# Java 8 : Fetching selective request parameters

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am trying to find all the request parameters which starts with `MultiFileId_` from a `request`

I am iterating over all the `request` key map and checkig whether each key starts with `MultiFileId_` and adding its value to a list if it matches

```
    List<String> uploadedFileIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Object p : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
        if(p.toString().startsWith("MultiFileId_")) {
            String uploadedFileId = request.getParameter(p.toString());
            uploadedFileIds.add(uploadedFileId);
        }
    }
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Java 8?

Comment: Is this a servlet? Can you confirm for reference exactly what class request is?

Comment: Its in my controller and `request` is of type `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're sure there is only one value per parameter:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example1 {
    public void example(HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<String> uploadedFileIds = Collections
                .list(request.getParameterNames())
                .stream()
                .filter(parameterName -> parameterName.startsWith("MultiFileId_"))
                .map(request::getParameter)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

If you're not sure whether parameters have multiple values (i.e., `request.getParameterValues("MultiFileId_XXX")` returning a `String[]` with `length > 1`), you could use:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example2 {
    public void example(HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<String> uploadedFileIds = Collections
                .list(request.getParameterNames())
                .stream()
                .filter(parameterName -> parameterName.startsWith("MultiFileId_"))
                .flatMap(parameterName -> Arrays.stream(
                        request.getParameterValues(parameterName)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: @tobias_k The `request.getParameterNames()` returns an `Enumeration`, oddly enough, so `Collections.list` turns it into a `List`, which is easier to work with.

Comment: @kuporific My bad, I mis-counted the parentheses and though you would pass in the result of `.collect`

Comment: @Necreaux I'm not sure. These are Java 8 classes and I've neglected to include the `imports`. I'll add the `imports` to my examples.

Comment: @kuporific Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate it. How do I avoid adding empty file ids to `uploadedFileIds` list?

Comment: @RanPaul Are you worried about `request.getParameter` returning `null`? If so, another call to `filter(param -> param != null)` could be added after the `flatMap()`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way:

```
List<String> uploadedFileIds = request.getParameterMap().entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("MultiFileId_"))
    .flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate it. How do I avoid adding empty file ids to `uploadedFileIds` list?

Comment: Add an additional filter after the flatMap(): `.filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())`

Comment: Thanks. looks like the filter returning `List<Object>` instead of `List<String>`

Comment: Why `.flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getValue()))` instead of `.map(e -> e.getValue())`? Besides that, streaming over the entryset is more efficient than streaming over the names (esp. with copying the `Enumeration` to a `List` first) and performing another lookup for each key…

Comment: @Holger because the map is a `Map<String, String[]>`. Each parameter name can have multiple values.

Comment: I see. Then I strongly recommend to use [`Arrays.stream(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) so every reader knows immediately what’s going on, without needing to see the generic signature. Otherwise, it’s impossible to tell apart [`Stream.of(T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) and [`Stream.of(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-)